# setting an overlay on video recording when in vertical orientation

Tags: android

So I have some code that records video normally. It uses a surface view to show what is recording. Here is the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/videoview"
            android:layout_width="720px"
            android:layout_height="480px"/>
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="REC"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So I understand that is an orientation change even.t How would I modify the given xml to include a View that would be hidden by default but on orientation change to vertical i can do setVisibility(true) on the overlay. I want to have warning text that says something along the lines of 'No recording vertical video'

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would want to [lock the orientation of the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) since you don't want the user to be able to interact in portrait mode.

Otherwise you can set your activity's [configchanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) to include orientation and keyboard hidden and update the view's visibility according to orientation in your `onConfigurationChanged` like so

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
     //something
    }

}
```

and in your `onCreate` by checking `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`